# More General term for "appliance operator"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In the HAM radio community the term "appliance operator" is used to describe people who use radio equipment but don't understand how the equipment works. In IT these people are disparagingly called Lusers.
http://www.eham.net/articles/11116
Is there a term for this in other broader contexts? In engineering what could you call a **technical** person without the underlying theoretical/technical understanding.

Comment: I don't think there's a common term across all disciplines. Each community has their own slang.

Comment: That (non-)technical person is in Business Development.

Answer (score 1):

The link you provide contrasts the *A.O.* with the average "Real Ham". They explain he might be using Ham for work, just as a tool. That's pretty much a *user* - *a person that uses* - as opposed to an *enthusiast*. Whereas [*Luser*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luser) is internet slang and derogatory, the *A.O.* is simply not fascinated by the hobby and is called out for that very purpose.

Answer (score 0):

'(Equipment) Operator' is the best thing I can think of.